# Subrequest MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm blocked on a subrequest I try to do, but I just can't see how to do.
I have 4 tables :

- jos_vm_products => All the products stored
- jos_vm_order_items => the items in an order
- jos_vm_order => an order
- stock_web_brut => the stock of my products

I want to get all the informations of a specific product :

- the number of stock (done)
- the informations of the product in the table jos_vm_products (done)
- the number of orders which are in « pending » for a specific product (blocked)

Here is the first request I have :

```
SELECT  `product_id` ,  `product_weight` ,  `cdate` ,  `mdate` ,  `product_name` ,  `product_sales` ,  `product_sku` ,  `product_in_stock` , SUM( stock_bloque ) AS  'stock_bloque', SUM( stock_total ) AS  'stock_total', SUM( stock_vente ) AS  'stock_vente', ref
FROM jos_vm_product t1
INNER JOIN  `stock_web_brut` t2 ON t1.product_sku LIKE CONCAT( t2.ref,  '%' ) 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

And I think I should do a subrequest like this :

```
SELECT 

     (
        SELECT  COUNT(t5.product_id) 
        FROM jos_vm_product t5 
        INNER JOIN jos_vm_order_item t6 ON  t5.product_id = t6.product_id 
        WHERE order_status = 'P' AND t5.product_id = 12
     ) AS "nombre_produit_pending",  
    `product_id` ,  
    `product_weight` ,  
    `cdate` ,  `mdate` ,  
    `product_name` ,  
    `product_sales` ,  
    `product_sku` ,  
    `product_in_stock` , 
    SUM( stock_bloque ) AS  'stock_bloque', 
    SUM( stock_total ) AS  'stock_total', 
    SUM( stock_vente ) AS  'stock_vente', 
    ref
FROM jos_vm_product t1
INNER JOIN  `stock_web_brut` t2 ON t1.product_sku LIKE CONCAT( t2.ref,  '%' ) 
GROUP BY product_id
```

And instead of « 12 », I thought I should do something like :

```
WHERE order_status = 'P' AND t5.product_id = t1.product_id
```

But I have a loop

Here are the tables : http://kai23.fr/myam.svg  (I can't post images)

And for the results, it would be something like that :

```
`product_id` | [...] | 'number_of_orders_in_pending_for_this_product' |
    12       | [...] |               15
    13       | [...] |               5
    14       | [...] |               3
```

If someone have an idea.

Kai23

Comment: Could you provide your table structure? Also what's your expected result would be?

Comment: Hello, here is a link with the full tables : 
    http://kai23.fr/myam.svg

And for the results, it would be something like that :
    `product_id` ,  
    [...]
    'stock_total', 
    'stock_vente', 
    'number_of_orders_in_pending_for_this_product'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the sub-select a bit wrong in this context. Use the sub-select in `left outer join`, something like this:

```
SELECT 
    `nombre_produit_pending`.`count`
    `product_id` ,  
    `product_weight` ,  
    `cdate` ,  `mdate` ,  
    `product_name` ,  
    `product_sales` ,  
    `product_sku` ,  
    `product_in_stock` , 
    SUM( stock_bloque ) AS  'stock_bloque', 
    SUM( stock_total ) AS  'stock_total', 
    SUM( stock_vente ) AS  'stock_vente', 
    ref
FROM jos_vm_product t1
INNER JOIN  `stock_web_brut` t2 ON t1.product_sku LIKE CONCAT( t2.ref,  '%' ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select count(t5.product_id) as count, t5.product_id as pid FROM jos_vm_product t5 
        INNER JOIN jos_vm_order_item t6 ON t5.product_id = t6.product_id 
        WHERE order_status = 'P'
     ) AS nombre_produit_pending ON nombre_produit_pending.pid = t1.product_id    
GROUP BY product_id
```

PS! I didn't check your database structure and the queries, I just copied Your own queries different order so if you get any errors from mysql I can help you sort them out :)

The point is that the sub-select should query ALL the pending orders and group them by ID (giving 2 values as return: `id` and `count`), so you join the sub-result with it's id and should have the respective count as a value.

Comment: I'm glad that You got it working :) Please mark the post as a solution as well if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to tiit, here is the final request :

```
SELECT 
`nombre_produit_pending`.`count`,
`product_id` ,  
`product_weight` ,  
`cdate` ,  `mdate` ,  
`product_name` ,  
`product_sales` ,  
`product_sku` ,  
`product_in_stock` , 
SUM( stock_bloque ) AS  'stock_bloque', 
SUM( stock_total ) AS  'stock_total', 
SUM( stock_vente ) AS  'stock_vente', 
ref
FROM jos_vm_product t1
INNER JOIN  `stock_web_brut` t2 ON t1.product_sku LIKE CONCAT( t2.ref,  '%' ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(t5.product_id) AS count, t5.product_id AS pid FROM         jos_vm_product t5 
    INNER JOIN jos_vm_order_item t6 ON t5.product_id = t6.product_id 
    WHERE order_status = 'P'
    GROUP BY t5.product_id
 ) AS nombre_produit_pending ON nombre_produit_pending.pid = t1.product_id    
GROUP BY product_id
```